# Unified Write Filter with WPA2-Enterprise PEAP-MSCHAPv2

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-registry, wifi-configuration, wpa2

hope you can help me. I can't seem to find the necessary answers.

We are developing an application which runs on top of Windows and hides the Windows UI. Therefore the user has no access to Windows. That's why we developed a webinterface, where the user can configure all the settings which are necessary for our application (like connecting to a Wifi).

When the user wants to add his WPA2-Enterprise network, where the EAP method type is **PEAP-MSCHAPv2**, he also has to set username and password.

Unfortunately it seems like Windows stores this data (username + password) in the registry, in **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** (HKCU) to be precise.
That's the key: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Wlansvc\UserData

Let's get to our problem: In UWF you can't exclude keys from HKCU, but only from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (HKLM). That's why the user can't add such network. He has to disable UWF, add the network again via the webinterface and enable UWF again.

Is there another (read: better) way to preserve this user data with UWF enabled?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just having the exact same problem with an application that stores a few settings in HKCU registry keys. Since it's neither possible to commit HKCU subkeys through UWF nor exclude them, it seems the only way around this is to exclude the path where the user part of the registry is from UWF completely. I haven't finished testing, but it looks as if adding a folder exclusion for "c:\users" does work. Of course, that makes any changes to the user part of the registry persistent.

Comment: Update: The above seems to be a _bad_ idea with Windows 10, Version 1909, but worked on previous versions. Starting with 1909, it may happen that after disabling the write filter, installing updates and re-enabling it, Windows suddenly fails to boot (initial startup screen with the turning wheel shown forever).